# Remove empty cells without changing the number of rows

Tags: matlab, cells

I have a **6x16 cell** (called **M**) sometimes with all the cell in the last 4 columns empty like this:

```
[12 200 3 4] [45 24 1 26]...[] [] [] []
...
[47 31 54 40] [85 2 10 256]...[] [] [] []
```

If I do

```
M=M(~cellfun('isempty',M));
```

then I end up with 72x1 cell. I would like the empty cells to be removed but the cell should become 6x12. By the way, in some cases the last 4 columns are not empty. In this case, I would like to preserve 6x16. Can anyone help?

Comment: The number of columns must be the same for all rows of a 2D cell array. You can't remove the last cells (columns) of only _some_ rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that last four columns are all empty, just contract `M`:

```
M = M(:,1:end-4);
```

If you don't know that four is always the number to exclude, you can try this:

```
nCol = size(M,2);
mask = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) nCol - numel([M{k,:}]),1:size(M,1),'UniformOutput',false)');
M    = M(:,1:end-max(mask));
```

This will trim the maximum number of columns that are empty.

Comment: Sorry I neglected to mention that sometimes the last 4 columns are not empty. I've corrected my question. I guess I could do an "if" in combination with your solution but that seems bulky.

Comment: @A.Rainer But do you still want a `6x12` regardless of the emptiness?

Comment: No, if the cells aren't empty, I would like to preserve 6x16.

Comment: Quick question: What are the variables d and k in your code? d is M?

Comment: @A.Rainer Sorry, `d` is supposed to be `M`.  `k` is an argument to the function handle given the `arrayfun`; it runs over the rows of `M`.